# AMF Login over Spring security

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to return some custom Authentication data using the details and/or the principal fields from that interface (org.springframework.security.core.Authentication) but nothing happens. 
The data returned on the other side of the Channel Set includes only the name and the authorities list (as Strings), and it's not useful enough

How can I transmit additional data on a Spring login request ?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully one can attach some custom data to a Spring Authentication instance (created by calling ChannelSet.login) as described in the following links:

- http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=89736&highlight=AuthenticationProcessingFilter

Comment: - http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=52529

- http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html

- http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/class-use/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html

Regards,

Dragos

Comment: The above did not work; 

Anyone knows how to return a custom response from an AuthenticationProvider?

With the tutorial settings, Spring removes everything except the user name and the roles....

Thanks